# SystemVerilog Class inside Generate

Tags: class, parameters, verilog, generate

I would like to use a SystemVerilog Class constructor inside a
generate-if statement using a parameter like so:

N is an input parameter.

```
generate begin
   if(N == 144) fft_144 fft = new; 
  else if(N == 180) fft_180 fft = new;  
end
endgenerate
```

This way I can use fft.something in the code. Vivado gives an error.

Thanks.

Comment: Show the error message. Show the declarations of everything in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog does not allow you to create dynamic objects (i.e. classes) outside of procedural blocks. So, you are missing somethning like `initial fft = new;`

Here is an example:

```
class A;
  function new();
  endfunction
endclass
class B;
  function new();
  endfunction
endclass

module C#(int N = 0)();
  A a;
  B b;
  if (N == 0)
    initial a = new;
  else 
    initial b = new;
endmodule
```